# How to efficiently insert data into index-rich oracle db?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

How do we insert data about 2 million rows into a oracle database table where we have many indexes on it?
I know that one option is disabling index and then inserting the data. Can anyone tell me what r the other options?

Comment: I think additional information is needed to provide a meaningful answer.  If UNDO is sized sufficiently, this isn't a problem if accomplishing the insert is the *only* goal.  Do you need the insert to be a single transaction for read consistency/rollback?  Is there concurrent DML to the table from other sources during the insert?  Is the nature of the application such that the time to perform this as a single operation prohibitive?

Comment: I would like the data to be inserted in a single transaction

Answer (score 1):

bulk load with presorted data in index key order

Answer (score 1):

Check [SQL*Loader](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Loader_FAQ) out (especially the paragraph about [performance optimization](http://Can_one_improve_the_performance_of_SQL.2ALoader.3F)) : it is the standard bulk loading utility for Oracle, and it does a good job once you know how to use it (as always with Oracle).

Answer (score 1):

there are many tricks to fasten de insert, below i wrote some of them

- if you use sequence.nextval for insert make sure sequence has big cache value (1000 is enough usually)
- drop indexes before insert and create afterwards (make sure you get the create scripts of indexes before dropping) while creating you can use parallel option
- if target table has fk dependencies disable them before insert and after insert enable again. if you are sure of your data you can use **novalidate** option (novalidate option is valid for **oracle**, other rdbms systems probably have similar option)
- if you select and insert you can give parallel hint for select statement and for insert you can use append hint (**direct-path insert** ) (direct-path insert concept is valid for **oracle**, other rdbms systems probably have similar option)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are inserting the records; if you can; insert the data in smaller chunks. In my experience 50 sets of 20k records is often quicker than 1 x 1000000

Make sure your database files are large enough before you start save you from database growth during the insert ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about the data, besides the index you can disable referential and constraint checks. You can also lower the transaction isolation level.

All these options come with a price, though. Each option increases your risk of having corrupt data in the sense that you may end up with null FK's etc.

Answer (score 0):

As an another option, one can use oracle advanced and faster data pump (expdp, impdp) utilities availability 10 G onward. Though, Oracle still supports old export/import (exp, imp).

Oracle provides us with many choices for data loading, some way faster than others:

- Oracle10 Data Pump Oracle import utility
- SQL insert and merge
- statements PL/SQL bulk loads for the forall PL/SQL operator
- SQL*Loader

[The pros/cons of each can be found here ..](http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_data_load.htm)